# Error: Can't walk dependency graph: ENOENT: no such file or directory, \cypress-cucumber-preprocessor\lib\getStepDefinitionsPaths.js

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I just want to ask for help because I can't run my feature file since the step definitions cannot be found

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7smDH.png)

Folder pattern
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFA85.jpg)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cypress": "^13.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
    "step_definitions": "cypress/e2e/cucumber/stepDefinitions/*"
```

}
}

cypress.config.js

```
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");



module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('file:preprocessor',cucumber())
    },
    specPattern: "cypress/e2e/cucumber/feature/*.feature",
  },
});
```

I'm trying to run my feature file, and getting an error

Answer (score 1):

You should change this dependency

```js
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1"
```

to this one

```js
"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^20.0.1",
```

The one you are using is no longer maintained, but the package has been taken over and re-branded with `@badeball` to allow you to pick the update a little easier.

The instructions for installing are given here [quick start](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md)